# aText not replacing Snippets in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, code-snippets, macvim

I used aText to fill in snippets for different functions across my computer, but it doesn't seem to be working with MacVim.

If I add shortcuts in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text, they work, but often they aren't very consistent. Sometimes I will have to type it a few times for it to work correctly. What might be hindering aText form auto-completing shortcuts in MacVim?

I just tested it, and it works perfect in normal Vim through the command line, but not through the MacVim app.

Comment: you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not really, I found it out has always, 'kind-of' worked. For instance, I have a shortcut that turns pers@ into my email address, and the first time I type it in MacVim it will just stay as pers@ but the second time it will actually transform into my address. It would be nice not having to erase the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using Typinator and it works fine in MacVim. I think there is a difference between how aText and MacVim call the text expansion.

Typinator is much more expensive, but I have come to prefer it over aText- especially with the Regex text expansion, and the fact that it works better in MacVim.